# Camel - Missing Dependencies : org.apache.camel.spi.ComponentResolver for dropbox

Tags: apache, dependencies, apache-camel, dropbox, apache-servicemix

I started to work on apache servicemix yesterday and I want to get all my files on my dropbox and put them on my local computer.
Here is the blueprint.xml which does it :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint
    xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0
      http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd">  

      <bean init-method="init" class="org.apache.camel.spi.ComponentResolver" id="componentResolver"/>
    <bean id="mySimpleRegistry" class="org.apache.camel.impl.SimpleRegistry"></bean> 

    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
     <propertyPlaceholder id="dropbox" location="dropbox.properties"/>
      <route>
        <from uri="dropbox://get?appKey=<>;appSecret=<>;accessToken=<>;path=/"/>

        <to uri="file:camel/output"/>
      </route>
    </camelContext>
</blueprint>
```

But it does nothing. So I checked what is the problem using bundle:diag.

```
Bundle 239
----------
Status: GracePeriod
Blueprint
22/03/17 14:49
Missing dependencies:
(&(component=dropbox)(objectClass=org.apache.camel.spi.ComponentResolver))
```

I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Go to servicemix console and use these commands:

`feature:install camel-dropbox`

Restart your bundle

`restart nnn` where nnn is your bundle I'd

Comment: An upvote/mark correct answer would be highly appreciated if your status permits. Happy it worked.